# how to categorize time values in pandas

Tags: pandas

Consider the dataframe below:

```
date=pd.DataFrame([02:00:00,04:00:00,07:00:00], columns=['time'])
```

I want to place these times into categories namely 2am-4am, 4am-7am etc. I know that pd.cut does this but it seems to not work for time values.

Comment: Are you still stuck?

Answer (score 0):

It will work for time also. Since we can use hour to bin it. `0-2 (hr) = 12 am - 2am`.

```
date=pd.DataFrame(["02:00:00","04:00:00","07:00:00"], columns=['time'])
date.time = pd.to_datetime(date.time)
bins = [0, 2, 4, 7, 13]
labels = ['12 am - 2 am', '2 am - 4 am', '4 am - 7am', '7 am - 1 pm']
res = pd.cut(date.time.dt.hour, bins, labels=labels, right=False)
```

---

**res:**

```
0    2 am - 4 am
1     4 am - 7am
2    7 am - 1 pm
Name: time, dtype: category
Categories (4, object): ['12 am - 2 am' < '2 am - 4 am' < '4 am - 7am' < '7 am - 1 pm']
```